# Getting forbidden error if I include csrf Spring security config for all non GET requests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, csrf

I created a Course API and wanted to authorize "ADMIN" and "USER" role users for GET request and only "ADMIN" role users for all other requests.

So keeping this requirement on my mind I wrote the below code.

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration {
    

    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    CustAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
    @Autowired
    CustomHeaderAuthFilter customAuthFilter;

    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/topics*").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/topics*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/topics*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/topics*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/hellos*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .formLogin().and().httpBasic();

        return http.build();
        
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("student").password("Student@1997").authorities("ROLE_USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("faculty").password("Faculty@1997").authorities("ROLE_ADMIN").and()
        .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        
    }
        
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

But I was getting forbidden error when I was logging in with "ROLE_ADMIN" too. Then I disabled csrf with the below code

```
http
 .csrf().disable();
```

Then It started working as expected. But I know removing csrf is not safe. So anyone can you please explain why I was not being authenticated if I add csrf and how to get around with this problem.

Comment: because the CSRF check is done before the authentication check for all requests that will mutate data on the server (POST, PUT, PATCH etc.) and failing CSRF will return 403 Forbidden, because you are not allowed to do a request unless you pass a CSRF token. You whern't even authenticated, because authentication errors fail with a 401 UNAUTHORIZED, not forbidden.

Comment: if you want to know the exact reason for things, i suggest you enable debug logs and look what the logs say as they will tell you the exact reason for the status code.